# kthread_run -- Purpose of last statement (__k;)

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am reading the linux kernel, specifically i am looking at the process creation and stumbled upon the following macro [1]

```
/**
 * kthread_run - create and wake a thread.
 * @threadfn: the function to run until signal_pending(current).
 * @data: data ptr for @threadfn.
 * @namefmt: printf-style name for the thread.
 *
 * Description: Convenient wrapper for kthread_create() followed by
 * wake_up_process().  Returns the kthread or ERR_PTR(-ENOMEM).
 */
#define kthread_run(threadfn, data, namefmt, ...)              \
({                                     \
    struct task_struct *__k                        \
        = kthread_create(threadfn, data, namefmt, ## __VA_ARGS__); \
    if (!IS_ERR(__k))                          \
        wake_up_process(__k);                      \
    __k;                                   \
})
```

My question is simple: What is the purpose of the last line's : `__k;`?

[1] http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kthread.h#L31

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That macro is a [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). __k is the return value (the thread pointer).
Statement expressions are a GCC extension that is also supported by clang.

Comment: Thank you i didn't know about this C extension, i will accept your answer later!